# Call action on button outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script where I add items to individual sections on the page. I will show you this by the example of one particular section. The problem appears with the c-grid-box, which is responsible for the fadeOut of the parent div. The anonymous function responsible for this action must be called outside of the diva addition function (otherwise I would have to add a function to each call that misses the target). For this I wrote something like this, although it still does not work - what could be the reason here?

```js
function showModal(type) {
         
  switch(type) {

    case "title":

    $(".overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#modal-inputs").html('<input type="text" placeholder="Title..." class="param-title" name="param-title" /><input type="text" placeholder="Description..." class="param-description" name="param-description" /><input type="submit" class="add-btn" id="insert-title" value="Insert" />');

    break;

  }
  
}

$("#add-text").on("click", function() {
   
  showModal("title");

  $("#insert-title").on("click", function() {
  
    title = $(".param-title").val();
    description = $(".param-description").val();
    $('#section-title').append('<div class="grid-1-5"><div class="grid_box"><a href="#" class="c-grid-box">Delete</i></a><p class="grid-box-title">'+title+'</p><p>'+description+'</p></div></div>');
    $(".overlay").fadeOut("slow");
    
  });
  
});

$(".grid_box").on("click", ".c-grid-box", function() {
  alert("foo bar");
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-text">
  <i class="fa fa-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  <p>Add <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</button>
            
<section class="add-box" id="section-title">
</section>

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="modal-box">
    <p class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>Settings 
      <a href="#" class="c-modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </p>
    <div id="modal-inputs">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should move out ur  `$("#insert-title")` out of  `$("#add-text")` scope, i don't see the point why event inside another event

Comment: It appears `.grid_box` is added dynamically.  You will need to attach the click function to an existing element - try `$("#section-title").on("click", ".c-grid-box", function() {`

Comment: @sideroxylon i create handler on ".add-box" and this way solved my problem ;)